# Error al ejecutar npm run dev en node console

Tags: laravel, vue.js, npm, webpack

Estoy siguiendo un tutorial de API  REST con Laravel y Vue JS, he creado unos componentes y unas rutas, pero al ejecutar el comando "npm run dev" obtengo un error:

He leído la documentación de webpacks en , pero no entiendo mucho sobre el manejo de webpacks.

probé instalando babel-preset-es2015 pero siguió con el mismo error.

Solicito de su ayuda para poder solucionar el siguiente error que sale en la consola de node.

[image: Error por consola]

Mi archivo app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue').default;

import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);

import Vue from 'vue';

import App from './App.vue';
import Home from '../js/components/Home.vue'
import ContactList from '../js/components/ContactList.vue';

import VueAxios from 'vue-axios';
import axios from 'axios';
Vue.use(VueAxios, axios);

const routes = [
 {
    name: '/',
    path: '/',
    component: Home
 }, {
    name: '/contacts',
    path: '/contacts',
    component: ContactList
 }
];

const router = new VueRouter({routes: routes});
const app = new Vue(Vue.util.extend(App)).$mount('#app');
```

Mi archivo webpack.mix.js

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');

mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
 .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
    //
]);
```

Mi archivo package.json

```
        {
        "private": true,
        "scripts": {
            "dev": "npm run development",
            "development": "mix",
            "watch": "mix watch",
            "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
            "hot": "mix watch --hot",
            "prod": "npm run production",
            "production": "mix --production"
        },
        "devDependencies": {
            "axios": "^0.21.1",
            "laravel-mix": "^6.0.6",
            "lodash": "^4.17.19",
            "postcss": "^8.1.14"
        },
        "dependencies": {
            "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
            "vue": "^2.6.12",
            "vue-axios": "^3.2.4",
            "vue-router": "^3.5.1"
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hola, podrías cambiar las imágenes, por código, de favor.

Comment: Intente modificando su archivo webpack.mix.js de la siguiente forma:                     `mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js').vue()
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        etc.....
    ])` y ejecute nuevamente npm run dev. Si no estoy mal, es por el tema de actualizaciones

Comment: Gracias @mafu me sirvió tu aporte para solucionar

Comment: @DiegoMartinez Que bueno, Saludos!